Additional properties are not allowed ('tool' was unexpected)Even Better TOML
when I add a file pdm.toml for python 3 project,
[pypi]
verify_ssl = true

# https://github.com/pdm-project/pdm/discussions/2406
[tool.pdm.resolution]
respect-source-order = true

[[tool.pdm.source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "http://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[[tool.pdm.source]]
name = "fallback"
url = "http://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

the toml file shows warning like this:
Additional properties are not allowed ('tool' was unexpected)Even Better TOML
Additional properties are not allowed ('tool' was unexpected)Even Better TOML
Additional properties are not allowed ('tool' was unexpected)Even Better TOML

this is the warning look like:

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue?

"the toml file shows warning like this:" - What does this mean? Specifically what steps do you take in order to make the warning appear, and exactly how and where does it appear?

Even Better TOML is reporting that tool is an incorrect application of the schema required for a pdm.toml, you should try this instead:
[pypi]
verify_ssl = true

# https://github.com/pdm-project/pdm/discussions/2406
[pdm.resolution]
respect-source-order = true

[[pdm.source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "http://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[[pdm.source]]
name = "fallback"
url = "http://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

If you prefer to keep the style you initially applied you should refactor pdm.toml to pyproject.toml

I have tried what you said, seems did not wok as expect.

try with the edited version. ('tool' was unexpected) probably only tool is incorrect.
Unfortunately I don't have VSCode to test it, and Even Better TOML is not available on PyCharm

the pycharm did not have these warning, maybe this issue was related with the vs code specify grammer check. I also tried the edited verson of config, still did not make the warning disappeared.

Not even refactoring pdm.toml to pyproject.toml?

refactoring to pyproject.toml still contains warning.
